# Follow-up question to "Combinatorial Proof of Fermat's Little Theorem"

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

The original problem has been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555828/combinatorial-proof-of-a-number-theory-theorem-confusion/2428444#2428444), which involves a necklace of $p$ beads each of which can be one of $a$ colors and shows that $a^p - a$ must be a multiple of $p$ by classifying the necklaces which are cyclic permutations of each other as indistinguishable and a necklace of length $p$ has $p$ cyclic permutations leading to $\frac{a^p - a}{p}$ distinct necklaces. Please see the [original](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555828/combinatorial-proof-of-a-number-theory-theorem-confusion/2428444#2428444) posting for details.

**Follow-up question:** Since there are $a!$ ways to permute the $a$ colors, is $\frac{a^p - a}{p}$ divisible by $a!$ ?

**Clarification:** We should assume $a < p$ if not use $a \bmod p$. This will lead to such necklaces where all $a$ colors used.

Comment: No. If you try to partition necklaces according to permuted colors, not all classes will have the same number of elements -- some necklaces have fewer recolorings, e.g. if the necklace has only one color, it has $a$ recolorings.

Comment: Not all colors are used in any necklace, so you don't get equivalence classes all of sizes $n!$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thanks for the response, please see the clarification I added to the question

Comment: No, some necklaces still only use, say, $2$ colors, no matter what $a$ is. So, for example, when you have $a=4$ and $p=5$, you could use $2$ colors in a necklace $RRBBB$. Then permuting the colors (and rotating the necklace) gives only $4\times 3\times 5=120$ arrangements, which is not divisible by $5\cdot 4!=240$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a=4\,,p=3\,$
$$\frac{4^3-4}{3×4×3×2}$$
$$\frac{64-4}{4×3×3×2}$$
$$\frac{60}{4×3^2×2}$$
$$\frac{5}{6}$$
Hence disproved

> The thing is, the necklaces you got may have such combinations where 1 color might have repeated less than $p$ times, $$$$(as you only discarded the ones which had 1 colour repeated $p$ times specifically)$$$$multiplying by $a!$ doesn't count those permutations

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is assuming that just because $a<p$ it means every color is used in every necklace.

That's not true. $a^p-a$ counts necklaces that use more than one color, and less than or equal to $a$ colors.

For example, if you take $p=5$, $a=4$, with colors Red, Blue, Green, Purple, then: "Red, Red, Blue, Blue, Blue" is counted in the $4^5-4$ necklaces.

Under permutation of colors and rotating the necklace, this necklace is equivalent to $5\cdot 4\cdot 3$ other necklaces.

But $5\cdot 4\cdot 3=60\neq p\cdot a!=120$. And we see that $\frac{4^5-4}{5}=204$ is not divisible by $a!=24$.

---

Of course, when $a\geq p$ you also get the problem - if you use $p$ distinct colors, you get that any rotation is also a color permutation. So there are just $a(a-1)\cdots(a-p+1)$ elements in the equivalence class of all necklaces using $p$ distinct colors.

We can prove combinatorially that $a(a-1)$ is a divisor of $a^p-a$.