# Question arising from combinatorial proof of Fermat's little theorem

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

The proof in question can be found here: [Combinatorial Proof Of A Number Theory Theorem--Confusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555828/combinatorial-proof-of-a-number-theory-theorem-confusion)

In cases where we attempt the process described in this proof with some non-prime $p$ for the necklace length, the proof fails to work because some cyclic permutations of a necklace of composite length may be identical to each other. For example, with $p=6$, and with the colors $B$ and $W$, we have the necklace: $BWBBWB$, which does not correspond to six *distinct* permutations, but only to three. Thus, we do not end up showing that $6|(2^6-2)$, and indeed it does not. Great.

In a discussion at a related question ([Why need prime number in Fermat's Little Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536229/why-need-prime-number-in-fermats-little-theorem/2536243?noredirect=1#comment5238240_2536243)), a question arose. In the non-prime case, is there a nice way to quantify the extent to which the proof breaks down? If $p$ is composite, can we write down a nice formula that counts the number of necklaces that appear fewer than $p$ times, and thus write $a^p-a$ as the sum of a multiple of $p$ and some other terms that depend on $p$ and $a$? Does the resulting error term reveal some number theoretic property of $p$?

Comment: Burnside's lemma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the non-prime case there are two related identities you can write down. First, as Lord Shark says in the comments, you can apply [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) to count the total number of necklaces up to cyclic permutation, which for necklaces of length $n$ using $a$ colors is

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d | n} \varphi(n/d) a^d.$$

where $\varphi(-)$ is the [totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). So you learn that $\sum_{d | n} \varphi(n/d) a^d$ is divisible by $n$; this reduces to FLT when $n$ is prime but gives an interesting generalization when $n$ is composite.

Another thing you can do is just count the number of aperiodic necklaces - the ones which are not equal to themselves under any nontrivial cyclic permutation - using [Mobius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula), which gives

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d | n} \mu(n/d) a^d$$

where $\mu(-)$ is the [Mobius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function). These polynomials $M_n(a)$ in $a$ are called [necklace polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_polynomial), and famously when $a = q$ is a prime power they count the number of monic irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$. In any case, here you learn that $\sum_{d | n} \mu(n/d) a^d$ is divisible by $n$. The necklace polynomials also appear in the [cyclotomic identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_identity)

$$\frac{1}{1 - at} = \prod_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{(1 - t^n)^{M_n(a)}}$$

which, when $a = q$ is a prime power, is a function field analogue of the Euler product factorization of the Riemann zeta function; see [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/11/03/the-cyclotomic-identity-and-lyndon-words/) for a combinatorial interpretation for arbitrary $a$.

I don't know if these congruences have a name; I call them the **necklace congruences**. They turn out to be equivalent, which is not obvious. A long time ago I wrote some blog posts about them which you can find [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/08/23/newtons-sums-necklace-congruences-and-zeta-functions/) and [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/11/04/newtons-sums-necklace-congruences-and-zeta-functions-ii/).

(These congruences admit a neat generalization to matrices, as follows. Instead of letting $a$ be an integer, let $A$ be a square matrix of integers. Then $\sum_{d | n} \varphi(n/d) \text{tr}(A^d)$ and $\sum_{d | n} \mu(n/d) \text{tr}(A^d)$ are divisible by $n$. The combinatorial interpretation involves thinking of $A$ as the adjacency matrix of a graph and counting closed walks on $A$ up to cyclic permutation.)

Comment: This answer is wonderful. Thank you so much!